# How to get feedback and preference choice regarding several design screenshots?

Tags: ab-testing, comparison

I would like to show several (2-3) design screenshots of web pages to users and get feedback to their choice.
Currently I am using UsabilityHub for that but the presentation of more than two screens and/or very long/wide screens is not quite good.
Are there any alternatives (which also offer 5sec. test optionally)?

Comment: What are your goals for the test?

Comment: To find out about the preference of a specific target group regarding one page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is seeking site suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this list can help you:
[uxdesign.cc/ux-tools-for-user-research-and-user-testing](https://uxdesign.cc/ux-tools-for-user-research-and-user-testing-a720131552e1)